# Angularjs partial not found

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs project. I am just wondering, how to show the user a message, if a requested view/partial is not found (HTTP 404). At the moment, angular starts the request and gets a 404 response including the error-html, but the user doesn't see any change to the website.

Answer (score 1):

Add an $http interceptor (scroll down on [this page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)) for 'responseError'

```
angular.module("app").config(function($provide, $httpProvider) {

// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {

   'responseError': function(response) {
      if (response.status == 404) {
        // user hit a 404 -- you can check response.url to see if it matches
        // your template directory and act accordingly
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');

});
```

Comment: Response interceptors are deprecated :/. And I am using $ressource not $http.

Comment: @leftjustified Mind the difference between `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` and `$httpProvider.interceptors`. `$resource` uses `$http` and in your question you talk about views. I see no connection to `$resource`.

Comment: Oh. Ok, sorry, my fault. I found a great blogpost on this topic: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/http-response-interceptors